# How to call the method in the different component

Tags: angular, typescript

**How to call a method in the different component using ViewChild ?**

I have created a method in the piechart component and tried to access that method from the app component usinf ViewChild.

**This is my piechart.component.ts**

```
export class PiechartComponent {
  constructor() { }
  pie(){
console.log("Hello World")
}
}
```

**This is my app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
 @ViewChild(PiechartComponent) piechart:PiechartComponent;
 constructor(){ }
 pieChart(){ 
 this.piechart.pie();
}
}
```

**This is my app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="pieChart()">Pie Chart</button>
```

When I click a button I should get output as "Hello world". But I am getting following error.
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'pie' of undefined"

Comment: you better change `angularjs` tag to `angular`

Comment: do you have pie component inside the app component's template?

Comment: I have took the reference of pie component in the app component. @TomaszKula

Comment: <button (click)="pieChart()">Pie Chart</button> - @Faisal

Comment: Add <app-pie-chart></app-pie-chart> to the app component.html

Comment: It worked. Thanks - @TomaszKula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the child component inside the parent component template

```
<pie-chart ></pie-chart>
<button (click)="pieChart()">Pie Chart</button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)